# Missing refrences to test libraries in test class

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, junit, kapt

I'm trying to run unit test on android module. This module has multiple product flavors with one dimension and two build types(debug + release). Also I have defined sourcesets for main, test and each of flavors.

What I'm struggling with is run any test in such module.

Only working solution is change dependency of test libraries from testImplementation to simple implementation.

code for app is in *src/nl/my-package* etc

code for test is in *src/test/java/nl/my-package* etc

```
 sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    test {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
    }

    dev {
        res.srcDirs = ['default/res']
    }

    stage {
        res.srcDirs = ['default/res']
    }
```

dependencies:

```
testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
testImplementation "org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.1"
testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.4.2"
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.13.0'
```

Code for simple test is:

```
package nl.my_package

import org.junit.Test

class CopyDisciplineSketchTest {

  @Test
  fun test() {
     assert(true)
  }
}
```

When I just run it using in project dependencies *kapt* as annotation processor than error is just
*error: incompatible types: NonExistentClass cannot be converted to Annotation*

but when I change it as suggested in another answers to simple *annotationProcessor* than error is 
*Unresolved reference: Test*

Has anybody idea how to deal with it?
In another modules of this project (which are simple data and domain modules without activities etc) such code works correct.

Comment: Why are you configuring the source sets instead of using project defaults?

Comment: What's the path to the file having the issue? Is it in the _KAPT_ build path?

Comment: @PFuster this is state of things in this project - not me to changing it now - too many files to update

Comment: @tynn file having issue is directly under src/test/package_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found solution.

```
    main { 
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
    }

    test {
        java.srcDirs = ['tests/java']
        resources.srcDirs = ['tests/java']
    }
```

where structure of folders is:
module_name/src/..
module_name/tests/..

Now everything works fine. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You defined `java.srcDirs = ['src']` and thus `'src/test/java'` is considered a part of the *Java* source tree.

You should consider to follow the project defaults and don't configure too much yourself. Otherwise you need to exclude the tests from your source sets manually:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
            exclude 'test/**'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was too quick and instead check on test in anotoher module :( Unfortunately this solution doesn't work

Comment: same as previous one after changing kapt to annotation processor.
current config for main is as you suggested:
java {
                srcDirs = ['src']
                exclude 'src/test/**'
            }

Comment: Still the same. Rebuilded project and nothing changed